# Bash script: generate 2 columns from a sringle string at a specific word/string

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns

I am trying to generate a table with 2 columns from a single string.

Example:

(From string)

```
*Col1*
a:axx
b:bxxxx
c:cx
*Col2*
d:dxx
e:exxxx
```

(To output)

```
*Col1*               *Col2*
a    axx             d     dxx
b    bxxxx           e     exxxx
c    cx
```

I already use `printf "str" | column -t -s ':'` in order to generate a table displaying everything in 1 column well aligned, but I don't know how to align a portion of the string as a second column.

I've looked up multiple variation such as `awk` and `paste`, but I still don't understand how to add them properly

Edit 1: forgot to mention that values are not all at identical length

Comment: What does "from string" mean exactly?

Comment: From the string above, it should give the print output below

Comment: So when you see a "line" in the string with leading and trailing asterisks, that's a new column?

Comment: Yes.....(filll)

Comment: do you know in advance that there are exactly 2 columns, and each field has a single colon?

Comment: Yes, always 2 columns, and a single column that divides the 'key' from its 'value'. the symbol to divide the key from the value can be changed, since its a script.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ echo "$value" | 
  awk -v OFS='\t' '
    /\*.*\*/ {c=0;n++;$0=$0 OFS}
             {a[++c,n]=$0} 
    max<c    {max=c} 
    END      {for(i=1;i<=max;i++) 
                for(j=1;j<=n;j++) 
                   {sub(/:/,OFS,a[i,j]); 
                    printf "%s",a[i,j] (j==n?ORS:OFS)}}'


*Col1*          *Col2*
a       a       d       d
b       b       e       e
c       c
```

but best to let `column` do the table formatting, just pipe the above to

```
... | column -nts$'\t'
```

so that it will work with uneven word lengths.  Using with the updated input file will give

```
*Col1*         *Col2*
a       axx    d       dxx
b       bxxxx  e       exxxx
c       cx
```

Comment: Your answer was perfect, but I forgot to mention that the values are not necessarily of identical length, therefore your answer give kind of a shift.

Answer (score 2):

Using `paste`:

```sh
s="${input//:/ }"
paste <(echo "${s%$'\n'\**}") <(echo "*${s#*$'\n'\*}") |
column -t -s $'\t'

*Col1*  *Col2*
a axx   d dxx
b bxxxx e exxxx
c cx
```

Where string is:

```sh
echo "$input"
*Col1*
a:axx
b:bxxxx
c:cx
*Col2*
d:dxx
e:exxxx
```

Comment: Your answere seems to copy the '*Col*........*Col*'

Comment: Don't understand your comment

Comment: Yeah, I cant seems to make columns and rows in the comment box.
But basically, it took col1, copied it and added it to its right. It took column 2, copied it and added it to its right. It copied the 1 column string and appended it to its right.

Comment: I have provided generated output for your edited question. Do you see anything wrong in that?

Answer (score 1):

Just using any awk in any shell on every Unix box for any number of columns and any number of fields:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=":"; colSep="\t"; fldSep="    " }
/^\*/ {
    tags[++numCols] = $0
    rowNr = 0
    next
}
{
    numRows = ( ++rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows )
    colNr = numCols
    colWid = (NF-1) * length(fldSep)
    for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
        vals[rowNr,colNr,fldNr] = $fldNr
        fldWid = length($fldNr)
        fldWids[colNr,fldNr] = ( fldWid > fldWids[colNr,fldNr] ? fldWid : fldWids[colNr,fldNr] )
        colWid += fldWid
    }
    colWids[colNr] = ( colWid > colWids[colNr] ? colWid : colWids[colNr] )
}
END {
    for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
        printf "%-*s%s", colWids[colNr], tags[colNr], (colNr<numCols ? colSep : ORS)
    }
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            val = ""
            for (fldNr=1; fldNr<=NF; fldNr++) {
                val = val sprintf( "%-*s%s", fldWids[colNr,fldNr], \
                        vals[rowNr,colNr,fldNr], (fldNr<NF ? fldSep : "") )
            }
            printf "%-*s%s", colWids[colNr], val, (colNr<numCols ? colSep : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
*Col1*          *Col2*
a    axx        d    dxx
b    bxxxx      e    exxxx
c    cx
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the keys are not just single letters:

```sh
$ echo "$value"
*Col1*
alfa:axx
bravo:bxxxx
charlie:cx
*Col2*
delta:dxx
echo:exxxx
```

Then, we can split the value into columns with sed, columnate each column, then join and columnate. I add some pipes into the 2nd column for visual purposes only:

```sh
paste <(sed    '/^\*Col2\*/,$ d'              <<<"$value" | column -ts:) \
      <(sed -n '/^\*Col2\*/,$ {s/^/|  /; p;}' <<<"$value" | column -ts:) \
| column -ts$'\t'
```

outputs

```
*Col1*          |  *Col2*
alfa     axx    |  delta   dxx
bravo    bxxxx  |  echo    exxxx
charlie  cx
```

Answer (score 0):

With the shell `sed` and `pr`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

string='*Col1*
a:axx
b:bxxxx
c:cx
*Col2*
d:dxx
e:exxxx'

echo "$string" | sed 's/:/  /' | pr -2t
```

---

Output

```
*Col1*                  *Col2*
a  axx                  d  dxx
b  bxxxx                e  exxxx
c  cx
```